# iOS IDFA (advertising identifier) is changing whenever relaunching app. Where is wrong in my swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, idfa

The following my code returns changed UUID string whenever I relaunch my app. Sometimes, it returns correct value (real IDFA) as "The Identifiers" iOS app is showing in "Advertising Identifier" field. It seems like round-robin??

I didn't reset the advertising identifier.
Anyone has the same experience?

```
import AdSupport

class IdManager {

    static func getIDFA() -> String? {
        if ASIdentifierManager.sharedManager().advertisingTrackingEnabled {
            return ASIdentifierManager.sharedManager().advertisingIdentifier.UUIDString
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I found that my local builds work correctly. Only builds uploaded to TestFlight and App Store shows wrong IDFA.